# I need SQL query from VCDB database for CPU and memory utilisation historical values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vmware

I need the sql query for the vmware cluster CPU and memory utlisation historcal values. i want to create a graph like shown in picture. can someone help me please?

DB name : vcdb (for vmware)
i am not able to find the exact table in that DB where i can get the values

Comment: This may get you started https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/87e080a0-a8c5-4193-b4d5-f20ebc4c2e00/which-vcenter-databasevcdb-table-stores-performace-data-hsitory-of-invidual-host?forum=sqltools

Comment: nope .. i have already checked this but it dows not give me historical values like.. last months value or before that